# Using the has() method a Laravel BelongsTo relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have an Activity model and a Level model. Each Activity has one Level, so I have the following on Activity:

```php
function level()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('Level');
}
```

And this on Level:

```php
function activities()
{
   return $this->hasMany('Activity');
}
```

I then need to search for Activities that have a particular Level, so I am doing this:

```php
$searchData = 'beginner';

$query = $query->has(array('level' => function($query) use ($searchData)
{
    $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchData . '%');
}));
```

Using this throws a LogicException:

```
Has method invalid on "belongsTo" relations.
```

So I've either got the relationship wrong or I need to build the query in a different way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How about `Level::with('activities')->where('name',$searchdata)->get();`

Comment: @TryingTobemyself, that would work but then I'm searching on the Level model. As I'm searching for Activities that have other relations too (such as Location, Type, etc), it makes sense to keep the search query as part of the Activity model. If possible.

Comment: @RussBack, then you could do 
`Level::with(array('activities','location','type'))->where('name',function($query) use($searchData){
  $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchData . '%');
})->get();`

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what does the DB model look like? Just wondering why you need to search for name with a string comparison function, instead of for instance level == X to find activities for a certain level, or level > Y to find activities above a certain level.

Comment: @TorkilJohnsen, yes you're right, my pseudo code isn't right there. I'd taken the code from another part of the application that has a many to many relationship and pivot table. Looking at it again from the beginning, the Activity model has a level_id so I could just say $query->wherelevel_id(X). Just out of interest though, if I didn't have the ID and instead had the string of an entry in the Level table, is there a way to look that up in the way I was trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this one, off it was answered in comments by @TorkilJohnsen.

I'd taken the code from another part of the application that has a many to many relationship and pivot table. Looking at it again from the beginning, the Activity model has a level_id so I can just do this:

```
$query->wherelevel_id(X)
```

Just out of interest though, if I didn't have the ID and instead had the string of an entry in the Level table, is there a way to look that up in the way I was trying? Presumably some sort of closure that looks up the level name and returns the ID?